# regex match multiple capture groups in any order

Tags: regex, perl, capture, regex-group

Given the sample string below I'm trying to capture the 'to', 'from', 'subject' and 'type' fields and spit them back out in a different format.  The issue is that these fields (to, from, etc) can be in any order.

SAMPLE STRING TO REGEX ON

```
<cfmail to="#toAddr#" from="#fromAddress" 
  subject="#subject#" type="html">
    #emailMsg#
</cfmail>
```

OUTPUT I'M LOOKING FOR

```
to:toAddr, from:fromAddress, subject:subject
```

If I knew that the order of those field I'm interested in was always the same then this is pretty easy, but I'm stumped on how to do this matching if, for instance, 'from' comes before 'to'

The perl one-liner I have right now is (just testing with 'to' and 'subject')

```
s/<cfmail.*?((to)="(.*?)")|((subject)="(.*?)").*<\/cfmail>/\1:\2, \3:\4/g
```

This ends up matching the 'to' value but stops there and I don't get anything for the 'subject' value.  I've tried several variations on this where I change matching group setup etc but have had no luck on it.

Comment: Why aren't you using a proper XML parsing library?

Comment: If you must do it with regex (well, you're using Perl...), then do it in two steps: First capture the substring `<cfmail(.*?)>`. Then do `s///g` with the alternatives as you did in your one-liner, but without matching the surrounding XML tags.

Comment: thanks Lenz.  I think your suggestion of breaking it up into steps is the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you need to allow for missing fields (e.g. no `type` field)?  What about other fields in addition to those four?  If you answered no to both questions, this regex should do the trick:

```
s!<cfmail(?:\s+to="(?<to>[^"]+)"|\s+from="(?<from>[^"]+)"|\s+subject="(?<subject>[^"]+)"|\s+type="(?<type>[^"]+)")+>.*?</cfmail>!to:$+{to}, from:$+{from}, subject:$+{subject}!gs
```

Here's the regex alone in more readable form:

```
<cfmail
(?:
  \s+to="(?<to>[^"]+)"
  |
  \s+from="(?<from>[^"]+)"
  |
  \s+subject="(?<subject>[^"]+)"
  |
  \s+type="(?<type>[^"]+)"
)+
>
.*?</cfmail>
```

...and a [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mE5wK0/1)

You were actually pretty close; alternation was the key.  You just needed to add a quantifier.

Notice that I removed the capturing groups from the field names.  You already know the names, you just need to pair them with the correct values.  The named groups make that much easier.